# Access denied for mv command in Git

Tags: git, powershell, command, mv

I am working on a project and I have initialized a Git repository in child folder. But I want to move it to the parent folder, so I ran this command:

```
mv .git ../
```

But I am getting the below error:

```
mv : Access to the path 'C:\Users\Ashish 
Vispute\OneDrive\Documents\a Real Estate Project\client\.git' is     
denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ mv .git ../
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\Ashish...ect\cl  
   ient\.git:DirectoryInfo) [Move-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveDirectoryItemIOError,Microsoft.Po  
   werShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

What should I do to resolve it, and which command should I run instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try to stop all processes associated with the folder and files (including code editors) and try again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35496977)